# Is there a way to automatically find the limits of integration given a set of constraints?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, assumptions

I have a complicated function $F(x,y,z)$ which I want to integrate subject to these constraints:

$y\geq z\geq-y, y \geq 0, y \leq \frac{x+z}{3}$.

It's only a 3D problem, so it's possible to draw a diagram to figure out the limits of integration. If I draw the lines $z=y$, $z=-y$, and $z=3y-x$ on pen and paper, the volume being integrated can be constrained. The answer turns out to be

$\int^{x/4}_0 dy \int^y_{-y} F(x,y,z)dz + \int^{x/2}_{x/4} dy \int^y_{3y-x} F(x,y,z) dz$

I am wondering if there's a way to do this automatically via Mathematica, especially since in 4 dimensions and higher I can't draw a diagram to visualize the limits of integration. The obvious way is to use a Mathematica command of the form:

```
Integrate[F, y, z, Assumptions -> (the conditions above)]
```

However adding the assumptions doesn't do anything and the result is the same as when the assumptions aren't there.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can directly integrate over the region defined by the conditions:

```
R = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= 1, {x, y}]
Integrate[x^2, {x, y} ∈ R]
```

> π/4

If this does not evaluate symbolically, you can still do it numerically with

```
NIntegrate[x^2, {x, y} ∈ R]
```

> 0.785398

Apparently, this does also work when the integration domain is a 2-dimensional surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$:

```
NIntegrate[x^2, {x, y, z} ∈ Sphere[]]
```

> 4.18879

Compare also to the following integral over the solid ball (a three-dimensional domain of integration):

```
Integrate[x^2, {x, y, z} ∈ Ball[]]
```

> (4 π)/15

I haven't checked it thouroughly, though.

Comment: Could instead use `Boole` and integrate over R^3.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau If you want to integrate over a surface (which is a null set for the three-dimensional Lebesgue measure), then you get result 0 from `NIntegrate[ x^2 Boole[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}]`.

Comment: Good point...(you gonna share that extra third of pie?)

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Do you mean _this third of pi_: `NIntegrate[1, {x, y, z} \[Element] 
  ImplicitRegion[0 <= z <= 1 && x^2 + y^2 <= z^2, {x, y, z}]]`?

Comment: (Heh) Yeah, that looks good. Blackberry, I think.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau suggest writing that as an answer, since for whatever reason (couldn't figure it out) ImplicitRegion didn't work for me but Boole did.

Comment: Per remark by @HenrikSchumacher, I'm not sure I can figure it out either (because the region has lower dimension than the ambient embedding space).

Comment: @Allure What exactly did not work? Do you have some code that you want to share?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher the code is rather technical. https://s22.postimg.cc/qmks8vi0h/Untitled.png. The ImplicitRegion integration output is truncated (it's massive, more than one screen long). This is in 3D to which I already know the answer (the one on the left is correct). The ImplicitRegion integration yields something that still has x, y, and z; since two of the three have been integrated over it should only have one variable left. I can't figure out what's wrong. The input looks superficially different, but the limits are just another way of saying lambda_1 > lambda_2 etc.

Comment: @Allure, I asked for code, not for images. Do you expect me to retype  all the stuff? Apart from that, you should consider to apply `DiscretizeRegion` before integration.

Comment: To be honest, I wasn't expecting you to try to run them (they take a while to execute on my computer). Do you still want the code typed out? Also, about DiscretizeRegion: what does this command do? The documentation says it turns the region into a MeshRegion, but I don't see how it would be helpful.

Comment: `DiscretizeRegion` approximates the region by small triangles or tetrahedra. Numerical integration over a triangle or a tetrahedron is simple. In fact, `NIntegrate` has to discretize the region anyway. But doing that by hand with `DiscretizeRegion` gives one the opportunity to tune the discretization (have a look at the options of `DiscretizeRegion`) and one can see what went wrong with the discretization.